# Remove title from ScatterChart

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I would like to know how to be able to assign a name just to a serie of data (using a scatterchart), without getting the same serie's name as title of the chart. I would like to get just the series name as legend and NOT chart title at all.

I realized that `autoTitleDeleted` needs to have a value of 1.

So, consulting documentation I found that ´chartContainer´ is the class to implement the aforementioned option. Therefore, I import the class and apply it as next:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.chart import (
        ScatterChart,
        Reference,
        Series,
)
from openpyxl.chart.chartspace import ChartContainer

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

rows = [
        ["Size", "Batch 1", "Batch 2"],
        [2, 40, 30],
        [3, 40, 25],
        [4, 50, 30],
        [5, 30, 25],
        [6, 25, 35],
        [7, 20, 40],
]

for row in rows:
    ws.append(row)    

chart2 = ScatterChart()

chart2.x_axis.title = "Size"
chart2.y_axis.title = "Percentage"

xvalues = Reference(ws, min_col = 1, min_row = 2, max_row = 7)
values = Reference(ws, min_col = 3, min_row = 1, max_row = 7)
series1 = Series(values, xvalues)
chart2.series.append(series1)

chart2 = ChartContainer(autoTitleDeleted = 1)

ws.add_chart(chart2, "J10")

wb.save("Ex1.xlsx")
```

However, next error comes up:

`runfile('C:/Users/Administrador/Desktop/Pre-Try/Ex1/Ex1.py', wdir='C:/Users/Administrador/Desktop/Pre-Try/Ex1')
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
    runfile('C:/Users/Administrador/Desktop/Pre-Try/Ex1/Ex1.py', wdir='C:/Users/Administrador/Desktop/Pre-Try/Ex1')

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "C:/Users/Administrador/Desktop/Pre-Try/Ex1/Ex1.py", line 46, in 
    wb.save("Ex1.xlsx")

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 397, in save
    save_workbook(self, filename)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 294, in save_workbook
    writer.save()

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 276, in save
    self.write_data()

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 76, in write_data
    self._write_worksheets()

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 219, in _write_worksheets
    self._write_drawing(ws._drawing)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 142, in _write_drawing
    self._archive.writestr(drawing.path[1:], tostring(drawing._write()))

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\drawing\spreadsheet_drawing.py", line 296, in _write
    self._rels.append(rel)

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'rel' referenced before assignment`

I do not really understand this error. If you could help would be grateful!

Comment: You need to include the complete traceback with the error, though I don't think it is related to what you're doing here.

Comment: Thank you for your help @CharlieClark. I have edited the question with traceback. Hope this could help to understand where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

`chart2 = ChartContainer(autoTitleDeleted = 1)`
This the problem: you must use openpyxl chart objects so that the library can manage the plumbing between objects: charts are very complicated objects and we try and hide some of the complexity Your idea is correct - to set the value to True – but that won't work like this because a `ChartContainer` doesn't know how to add itself to the XLSX package.

As a workaround it's probably easiest create a title with an empty string. Otherwise you could submit a PR that allows the mapping of the `autoTitleDeleted` attribute from chartContainers to charts and vice versa.

Comment: Hi @Charlie. Thank you for your answer. Nonetheless, the workaround you commented does not resolve the problem because the "title space" is still there (although without any word), so the plot area is smaller than it shoud be. Is there any other way of removing the title?

Comment: No, not without making changes to the library as I've described.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer @Charile. Yes, I have read your other option. However, I am not sure whether I have enough knowledge and experience to do that..